# how to write a code in vba so each time a function call its create a different sheet in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

```
 Public Sub text1(st As String)
    Dim oXL As Object        ' Excel application
    Dim oBook As Object      ' Excel workbook
    Dim oSheet As Object     ' Excel Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer


    'Start Excel and create a new workbook
    Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.application")
    Set oBook = oXL.Workbooks.Open("E:\karan.xlsx")
    Set ws = oBook.Sheets.Add
    oBook.activesheet.Name = st
    ws.Activate
```

Comment: @dwirony - `st` will be a value passed through to the sub.  @OP - does this not do what you want? It should be creating a new worksheet.  Also, what are you running this from? Note that it'll create a sheet named  `st`,  so as long as that changes, then it should work. Note you probably want `ws.Name = st` instead though.

Answer (score 0):

To what I understand you, you would like to add a workbook when your function is called. In such a case you could use this:

```
Sub AddWorkbook()
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
End Sub
```

If you additionally want to add a name:

```
Private Sub AddWorkbookWithName(workbookName As String)
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = workbookName
End Sub

Sub AddWorkbook()
    AddWorkbookWithName ("MyWorkbookName")
End Sub
```